# what is wrong about this code. I tried to load a test file as input streams?

Tags: java

Code for loading test file as input streams

```java
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {

      // file input.txt is loaded as input stream
      // input.txt file contains:
      // This is a content of the file input.txt
      InputStream input = new FileInputStream("input.txt");

      System.out.println("Data in the file: ");

      // Reads the first byte
      int i = input.read();

      while(i != 1) {
        System.out.print((char)i);

        // Reads next byte from the file
        i = input.read();
      }
      input.close();
    }

    catch(Exception e) {
      e.getStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. Describe in detail what's happening when you run your code or what exceptions / errors you are encountering. Currently you only posted your code without any detailed information about what's wrong, so people won't really be able to help you. (Also improve the post title to something meaningful).

Comment: You should probably give FileInlutStream the full path instead of just the filename

Comment: can you explain, what are you trying to do here

Comment: details are missing

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the problem is in the condition of your while statement. The end of file is reached **when the int value is -1 rather than 1**

```
while (i != -1) {}
```

Second, the e.getStackTrace() won't print anything as it only gets the stack trace.

Finally, here is a working code snippet:

```
try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream(filePath)) {
        int i = input.read();

        while(i != -1) {
            System.out.print((char) i);
            i = input.read();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```